# Improving a recursive hadamard transformation

Tags: c, simd, avx

I have the following code to calculate a Hadamard transform. Right now, the hadamard function is the bottleneck of my program. Do you see any potential to speed it up? Maybe using AVX2 instructions? Typical input sizes are around 512 or 1024.

Best, Tom

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hadamard(double *p, size_t len) {
    double tmp = 0.0;

    if(len == 2) {
        tmp = p[0];
        p[0] = tmp + p[1];
        p[1] = tmp - p[1];
    } else {
        hadamard(p, len/2);
        hadamard(p+len/2, len/2);

        for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
           tmp = p[i];
           p[i] = tmp + p[i+len/2];
           p[i+len/2] = tmp - p[i+len/2];
       }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        double a[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

        hadamard(a, 4);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to hear more about the workflow you're using where computing the Hadamard matrix is the bottleneck. Can you elaborate more on what you're doing? It might be possible to, say, hardcode some of these matrices into the program or to stash them in data files and then mmap them in as needed. Or perhaps you're recomputing them too many times and could just cache what you're producing.

Comment: You can definitely eliminate some code. That won't improve the performance, but will make it cleaner. For example - `len/2` can be calculated only once and not all over the whole function.

Comment: I think this is off topic for SO. My understanding is that you could get a code review, and suggestions for improvements, at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ref: [Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform)

Comment: It's part of a code where I have to convolve vectors and replace the convolution by the Hadamard transform to decrease complexity from O(n^2) to O(N*log(N)). Unfortunately, it gets called so often that it is still a bottleneck. I replaced then len/2 calls in the meantime, but I think the compiler already did this for me ;)

Comment: @tomseidel1 Are you recomputing the same matrices over and over and over again? If so, just computing the matrix once should work wonders.

Comment: You can see what I am doing above :) I have a recursive implementation and I don't calculate any matrices at all, but exploit the butterfly structure.

Comment: @templatetypedef Explicitly computing the matrix would not make sense, since matrix-vector products are `O(n^2)`, but the transform can be computed in `O(n*log(n))`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform

Comment: You definitely want to open-code a larger base case, maybe something like size = 16 (four vectors of 4 `double` each).  Are you sure you need `double`, not `float`?  With SIMD, half the element size means twice as much work per vector.  On the flip side, horizontal stuff can take more shuffling of elements inside one vector.

Comment: x265 (the video codec) has x86 NASM macros for Hadamard transforms on 8 and 16-bit integer data.  See https://github.com/videolan/x265/blob/aaa112abf66c88730e679e574c5b5be83bf5659b/source/common/x86/x86util.asm#L563 for the HADAMARD macro used by HADAMARD_2D. It's defined in terms of *other* macros.  (x264 and x265 make more use of macros than most hand-written asm projects, it can be pretty hard to follow.  Maybe looking at disassembly of a compiled version can help.)  You might be able to adapt some of the ideas in the horizontal or vertical part of that code for your 1D use-case.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof-of-concept implementation, based on the [Fast Walsh–Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform), with an optimized first pass. Compiles fine with clang-3.3 or later, and gives nice results with [clang-4.0 or later](https://godbolt.org/z/mDEJcB) (requires -O2 to properly inline relevant functions). If you don't have FMA, you need to xor the lower two elements of `hada2_` with `-0.0` in `hadamard4` (and use a normal `_mm256_add_pd`).

All gcc versions I checked would require replacing the `memcpy` by manual load/store intrinsics to get similar results.

Also, I left handling of cases `len<16` as exercise. And it may be worth implementing a `hadamard32` and perhaps a `hadamard64` similar to `hadamard16`, to better use the available registers and reduce memory access. In C++ this could be done with a recursive template implementation.

```
#include <immintrin.h> // avx+fma
#include <assert.h> // assert
#include <string.h> // memcpy

inline __m256d hadamard4(__m256d x0123)
{
    __m256d x1032 = _mm256_permute_pd(x0123, 5);             // [x1, x0, x3, x2]

    __m256d hada2 = _mm256_addsub_pd(x1032,x0123);           // [x0+x1, x0-x1, x2+x3, x2-x3]
    __m256d hada2_= _mm256_permute2f128_pd(hada2, hada2, 1); // [x2+x3, x2-x3, x0+x1, x0-x1]
    // if no FMA is available, this can be done with xoring and adding:
    __m256d res   = _mm256_fmadd_pd(hada2_, _mm256_set_pd(1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0), hada2);

    return res;
}

inline void hadamard8(__m256d data[2])
{
    __m256d a = hadamard4(data[0]);
    __m256d b = hadamard4(data[1]);
    data[0] = _mm256_add_pd(a,b);
    data[1] = _mm256_sub_pd(a,b);
}

inline void hadamard16(__m256d data[4])
{
    hadamard8(data+0);
    hadamard8(data+2);
    for(int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    {
        __m256d tmp = data[i];
        data[i]  = _mm256_add_pd(tmp, data[i+2]);
        data[i+2]= _mm256_sub_pd(tmp, data[i+2]);
    }
}

void hadamard(double* p, size_t len)
{
    assert((len&(len-1))==0); // len must be power of 2
    assert(len>=16); // TODO implement fallback for smaller sizes ...

    // first pass: hadamard of 16 values each
    for(size_t i=0; i<len; i+=16)
    {
        __m256d data[4];
        memcpy(data, p+i, sizeof(data)); // should get optimized to 4x vmovupd
        hadamard16(data);
        memcpy(p+i, data, sizeof(data)); // should get optimized to 4x vmovupd

    }
    for(size_t h=32; h<len; h*=2)
    {
        for(size_t i=0; i<len; i+=2*h)
        {
            for(size_t j=i; j<i+h; j+=4)
            {
                __m256d x = _mm256_loadu_pd(p+j);
                __m256d y = _mm256_loadu_pd(p+j+h);
                _mm256_storeu_pd(p+j,   _mm256_add_pd(x,y));
                _mm256_storeu_pd(p+j+h, _mm256_sub_pd(x,y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Benchmarking is also left as an exercise ;-)

Disclaimer: I did not test this. Looking at it, I may have mixed up `hada2_` and `hada2` in the `_mm256_fmadd_pd` instruction ...

Comment: Thank you very much @chtz! This helped a lot. I had to modify three things:
1. I reversed the order of the _mm256_set_pd() arguments to -1.0, -1.0, 1, 1, as the left-most value ends in the very right when I convert the result to a double again.
2. The arguments to fmadd_pd need to be swapped (as you correctly pointed out).
3. I needed another `hada2 = _mm256_permute_pd(hada2,5);` after the addsub.

The speedup is about a factor of 2-3. That's very neat! However, this raises again a few questions for me as I would like to learn from this example:

Comment: 1. I also came up with an AVX2 version, which also works, but did not bring any speed-ups. For this, I tried to replaced the loop after the two recursive calls in the above functions with its AVX counterpart, i.e., doing simple `_mm256_add` and `_mm256_sub` on the respective parts of length-4 of the variable `p`.
2. How did you know that a good approach is to start with a transform of 4 and then going up? Why not starting with 8 or 16?
3. Following @Peter Cordes idea of using floats: Can we expect an even better performance here for lengths of 512?