# Fast algorithm for computing intersections of N sets

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, intersection, simd

I have n sets A0,A2,...An-1 holding items of a set E.

I define a configuration C as the integer made of n bits, so C has values between 0 and 2^n-1. Now, I define the following:

```
(C)   an item e of E is in configuration C 
       <=> for each bit b of C, if b==1 then e is in Ab, else e is not in Ab
```

For instance for n=3, the configuration C=011 corresponds to items of E that are in A0 and A1 but NOT in A2 (the NOT is important)

**`C[bitmap]` is the count of elements that have exactly that presence/absence pattern in the sets.**  `C[001]` is the number of elements in A0 that aren't also in any other sets.

---

Another possible definition is :

```
(V)   an item e of E is in configuration V 
       <=> for each bit b of V, if b==1 then e is in Ab
```

For instance for n=3, the (V) configuration V=011 corresponds to items of E that are in A0 and A1

**`V[bitmap]` is the count of the intersection of the selected sets.**  (i.e. the count of how many elements are in all of the sets where the bitmap is true.)  `V[001]` is the number of elements in A0.  `V[011]` is the number of elements in A0 *and* A1, regardless of whether or not they're also in A2.

---

In the following, the first picture shows items of sets A0, A1 and A2, the second picture shows size of (C) configurations and the third picture shows size of (V) configurations.

[image: sets examples]
[image]
[image]

I can also represent the configurations by either of two vectors:

```
C[001]= 5       V[001]=14
C[010]=10       V[010]=22
C[100]=11       V[100]=24
C[011]= 2       V[011]= 6
C[101]= 3       V[101]= 7
C[110]= 6       V[110]=10
C[111]= 4       V[111]= 4
```

**What I want is to write a C/C++ function that transforms C into V as efficiently as possible**. A naive approach could be the following 'transfo' function that is obviously in O(4^n) :

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

vector<size_t> transfo (const vector<size_t>& C)
{
    vector<size_t> V (C.size());

    for (size_t i=0; i<C.size(); i++)
    {
        V[i] = 0;

        for (size_t j=0; j<C.size(); j++)
        {
            if ((j&i)==i)  { V[i] += C[j]; }
        }
    }

    return V;
} 


int main()
{
    vector<size_t> C = { 
        /* 000 */  0,
        /* 001 */  5,
        /* 010 */ 10,
        /* 011 */  2,
        /* 100 */ 11,
        /* 101 */  3,
        /* 110 */  6,
        /* 111 */  4
    };

    vector<size_t> V = transfo (C);

    for (size_t i=1; i<V.size(); i++)  {  printf ("[%2ld]  C=%2ld   V=%2ld\n", i, C[i], V[i]);  }
}
```

My question is : **is there a more efficient algorithm than the naive one for transforming a vector C into a vector V ? And what would be the complexity of such a "good" algorithm ?**

Note that I could be interested by any SIMD solution.

Comment: For SIMD optimization for real problems, do you have a typical `n` in mind?  Are we talking about looping over thousands of `C` values?  Or would all the `C` values fit in a single SIMD vector and need shuffling?  Do the counts really need to be `size_t` (typically 64-bit), or would a narrower integer type like `uint16_t` or `uint8_t` work?  (More elements per SIMD vector is often more efficient, depending on what amount of shuffling is needed.  And horizontal sums of `uint8_t` is really efficient on x86 with [`psadbw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSADBW.html) against 0).

Comment: From an implementation POV, it might help the compiler to sum into a tmp var inside the inner loop, and store that to `V[i]` at the end.  Alias analysis between two `std::vector`s of the same type might not be perfect.  Also, for single-bit-set `i` values, it might be worth trying to do less work by skipping ranges of `j` values.  But it's going to be hard to make that efficient.

Comment: You could implement the conditional-sum with SIMD somewhat similar to  [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](//stackoverflow.com/q/54541129).  Keep a SIMD vector of `i` values (probably every element the same) and `j` values (e.g. 16 consecutive values).  SIMD AND, then compare the result against the `i` vector to implement `(i&j) == i`, and use that to mask a SIMD load from `C[j + 0..16]`, which you `_mm_add_epi8` or `epi16` (or 32 or 64) into a vector accumulator.  (So you add `0` for some elements.)  Use wide enough elements that you can hsum after, or 8-bit for PSADBW.

Comment: Somewhat similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097024/improving-a-recursive-hadamard-transformation. You need to replace the Hadamard-matrix by the Sierpinski matrix (i.e., replace the `-1` by `0`). The actual implementation depends on what input/output types you actually want (how many bits do you actually need) and what target architecture you are aiming at.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you are trying to compute 2<sup>n</sup> values, so you cannot do better than O(2<sup>n</sup>).

The naive approach starts from the observation that V[X] is obtained by fixing all the 1 bits in X and iterating over all the possible values where the 0 bits are. For example,

```
V[010] = C[010] + C[011] + C[110] + C[111]
```

But this approach performs O(2<sup>n</sup>) additions for every element of V, yielding a total complexity of O(4<sup>n</sup>).

Here is an O(n × 2<sup>n</sup>) algorithm. I too am curious if an O(2<sup>n</sup>) algorithm exists.

Let `n = 4`. Let us consider the full table of V versus C. Each line in the table below corresponds to one value of V and this value is calculated by summing up the columns marked with a `*`. The layout of `*` symbols can be easily deduced from the naive approach.

```
    |0000|0001|0010|0011|0100|0101|0110|0111||1000|1001|1010|1011|1100|1101|1110|1111
0000| *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  || *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  
0001|    | *  |    | *  |    | *  |    | *  ||    | *  |    | *  |    | *  |    | *  
0010|    |    | *  | *  |    |    | *  | *  ||    |    | *  | *  |    |    | *  | *  
0011|    |    |    | *  |    |    |    | *  ||    |    |    | *  |    |    |    | *  
0100|    |    |    |    | *  | *  | *  | *  ||    |    |    |    | *  | *  | *  | *  
0101|    |    |    |    |    | *  |    | *  ||    |    |    |    |    | *  |    | *  
0110|    |    |    |    |    |    | *  | *  ||    |    |    |    |    |    | *  | *  
0111|    |    |    |    |    |    |    | *  ||    |    |    |    |    |    |    | *  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    || *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  | *  
1001|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ||    | *  |    | *  |    | *  |    | *  
1010|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ||    |    | *  | *  |    |    | *  | *  
1011|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ||    |    |    | *  |    |    |    | *  
1100|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ||    |    |    |    | *  | *  | *  | *  
1101|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ||    |    |    |    |    | *  |    | *  
1110|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ||    |    |    |    |    |    | *  | *  
1111|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ||    |    |    |    |    |    |    | *
```

Notice that the top-left, top-right and bottom-right corners contain identical layouts. Therefore, we can perform some calculations in bulk as follows:

1. Compute the bottom half of the table (the bottom-right corner).
2. Add the values to the top half.
3. Compute the top-left corner.

If we let q = 2<sup>n</sup>, Thus the recurrent complexity is

T(q) = 2T(q/2) + O(q)

which solves using the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) to

T(q) = O(q log q)

or, in terms of n,

T(n) = O(n × 2<sup>n</sup>)

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. However, I would have switch steps 2 and 3 in order to process the two recursive calls before adding the values during step 2. Otherwise (at least in the implementation I tried from your answer), won't it be possible to count too many times some values ? I will provide my implementation of your suggestion as an answer if my original question is re-opened.

Comment: We meet again, [Mr Sierpiński](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle).

Comment: For a non-recursive algorithm, check out the similar [Fast Walsh-Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform). Only remove all the subtractions (and adapt the ordering).

Answer (score 3):

According to the great observation of @CătălinFrâncu, I wrote two recursive implementations of the transformation (see code below) :

- `transfo_recursive`: very straightforward recursive implementation
- `transfo_avx2` : still recursive but use AVX2 for last step of the recursion for n=3

I propose here that the sizes of the counters are coded on 32 bits and that the n value can grow up to 28.

I also wrote an iterative implementation (`transfo_iterative`) based on my own observation on the recursion behaviour. Actually, I guess it is close to the non recursive implementation proposed by @chtz.

Here is the benchmark code:

```
// compiled with: g++ -O3   intersect.cpp -march=native -mavx2 -lpthread -DNDEBUG

#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <boost/align/aligned_allocator.hpp>

using namespace std;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef u_int32_t Count;

// Note: alignment is important for AVX2
typedef std::vector<Count,boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<Count, 8*sizeof(Count)>>  CountVector;

typedef void (*callback) (CountVector::pointer C, size_t q);
typedef vector<pair<const char*, callback>> FunctionsVector;

unsigned int randomSeed = 0;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double timestamp()
{
    struct timespec timet;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &timet);
    return timet.tv_sec + (timet.tv_nsec/ 1000000000.0);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CountVector getRandomVector (size_t n)
{
    // We use the same seed, so we'll get the same random values
    srand (randomSeed);

    // We fill a vector of size q=2^n with random values
    CountVector C(1ULL<<n);
    for (size_t i=0; i<C.size(); i++)  { C[i] = rand() % (1ULL<<(8*sizeof(Count))); }
    return C;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void copy_add_block (CountVector::pointer C, size_t q)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<q/2; i++)   {  C[i] += C[i+q/2]; }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void copy_add_block_avx2 (CountVector::pointer C, size_t q)
{
    __m256i* target = (__m256i*) (C);
    __m256i* source = (__m256i*) (C+q/2);

    size_t imax = q/(2*8);

    for (size_t i=0; i<imax; i++)
    {
        target[i] = _mm256_add_epi32 (source[i], target[i]);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Naive approach : O(4^n)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CountVector transfo_naive (const CountVector& C)
{
    CountVector V (C.size());

    for (size_t i=0; i<C.size(); i++)
    {
        V[i] = 0;

        for (size_t j=0; j<C.size(); j++)
        {
            if ((j&i)==i)  { V[i] += C[j]; }
        }
    }

    return V;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Recursive approach : O(n.2^n)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void transfo_recursive (CountVector::pointer C, size_t q)
{
    if (q>1)
    {
        transfo_recursive (C+q/2, q/2);
        transfo_recursive (C,     q/2);

        copy_add_block (C, q);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Iterative approach : O(n.2^n)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void transfo_iterative (CountVector::pointer C, size_t q)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for (size_t n=q; n>1; n>>=1, i++)
    {
        size_t d = 1<<i;

        for (ssize_t j=q-1-d; j>=0; j--)
        {
            if ( ((j>>i)&1)==0) { C[j] += C[j+d]; }
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Recursive AVX2 approach : O(n.2^n)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define ROTATE1(s)  _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32 (s, _mm256_set_epi32(0,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
#define ROTATE2(s)  _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32 (s, _mm256_set_epi32(0,0,7,6,5,4,3,2))
#define ROTATE4(s)  _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32 (s, _mm256_set_epi32(0,0,0,0,7,6,5,4))

void transfo_avx2 (CountVector::pointer V, size_t N)
{
    __m256i k1 = _mm256_set_epi32 (0,0xFFFFFFFF,0,0xFFFFFFFF,0,0xFFFFFFFF,0,0xFFFFFFFF);
    __m256i k2 = _mm256_set_epi32 (0,0,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0,0,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF);
    __m256i k4 = _mm256_set_epi32 (0,0,0,0,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF);

    if (N==8)
    {
        __m256i* source = (__m256i*) (V);

        *source = _mm256_add_epi32 (*source, _mm256_and_si256(ROTATE1(*source),k1));
        *source = _mm256_add_epi32 (*source, _mm256_and_si256(ROTATE2(*source),k2));
        *source = _mm256_add_epi32 (*source, _mm256_and_si256(ROTATE4(*source),k4));
    }
    else // if (N>8)
    {
        transfo_avx2 (V+N/2, N/2);
        transfo_avx2 (V,     N/2);

        copy_add_block_avx2  (V, N);
    }
}

#define ROTATE1_AND(s)  _mm256_srli_epi64 ((s), 32)  // odd 32bit elements
#define ROTATE2_AND(s)  _mm256_bsrli_epi128 ((s), 8) // high 64bit halves
// gcc doesn't have _mm256_zextsi128_si256
// and _mm256_castsi128_si256 doesn't guarantee zero extension
// vperm2i118 can do the same job as vextracti128, but is slower on Ryzen
#ifdef __clang__                                      // high 128bit lane
#define ROTATE4_AND(s)  _mm256_zextsi128_si256(_mm256_extracti128_si256((s),1))
#else
//#define ROTATE4_AND(s)  _mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm256_extracti128_si256((s),1))
#define ROTATE4_AND(s)  _mm256_permute2x128_si256((s),(s),0x81)  // high bit set = zero that lane
#endif

void transfo_avx2_pcordes (CountVector::pointer C, size_t q)
{
    if (q==8)
    {
        __m256i* source = (__m256i*) (C);
        __m256i tmp = *source;
        tmp = _mm256_add_epi32 (tmp, ROTATE1_AND(tmp));
        tmp = _mm256_add_epi32 (tmp, ROTATE2_AND(tmp));
        tmp = _mm256_add_epi32 (tmp, ROTATE4_AND(tmp));
        *source = tmp;
    }
    else //if (N>8)
    {
        transfo_avx2_pcordes (C+q/2, q/2);
        transfo_avx2_pcordes (C,     q/2);

        copy_add_block_avx2  (C, q);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Template specialization (same as transfo_avx2_pcordes)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <int n>
void transfo_template (__m256i* C)
{
    const size_t q = 1ULL << n;

    transfo_template<n-1> (C);
    transfo_template<n-1> (C + q/2);

    __m256i* target = (__m256i*) (C);
    __m256i* source = (__m256i*) (C+q/2);

    for (size_t i=0; i<q/2; i++)
    {
        target[i] = _mm256_add_epi32 (source[i], target[i]);
    }
}

template <>
void transfo_template<0> (__m256i* C)
{
    __m256i* source = (__m256i*) (C);
    __m256i tmp = *source;
    tmp = _mm256_add_epi32 (tmp, ROTATE1_AND(tmp));
    tmp = _mm256_add_epi32 (tmp, ROTATE2_AND(tmp));
    tmp = _mm256_add_epi32 (tmp, ROTATE4_AND(tmp));
    *source = tmp;
}

void transfo_recur_template (CountVector::pointer C, size_t q)
{
#define CASE(n)     case 1ULL<<n: transfo_template<n> ((__m256i*)C);   break;

    q = q / 8; // 8 is the number of 32 bits items in the AVX2 registers

    // We have to 'link' the dynamic value of q with a static template specialization
    switch (q)
    {
                  CASE( 1); CASE( 2); CASE( 3); CASE( 4); CASE( 5); CASE( 6); CASE( 7); CASE( 8); CASE( 9);
        CASE(10); CASE(11); CASE(12); CASE(13); CASE(14); CASE(15); CASE(16); CASE(17); CASE(18); CASE(19);
        CASE(20); CASE(21); CASE(22); CASE(23); CASE(24); CASE(25); CASE(26); CASE(27); CASE(28); CASE(29);

        default: printf ("transfo_template undefined for q=%ld\n", q);  break;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Recursive approach multithread : O(n.2^n)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void transfo_recur_thread (CountVector::pointer C, size_t q)
{
    std::thread t1 (transfo_recur_template, C+q/2, q/2);
    std::thread t2 (transfo_recur_template, C,     q/2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    copy_add_block_avx2 (C, q);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void header (const char* title, const FunctionsVector& functions)
{
    printf ("\n");
    for (size_t i=0; i<functions.size(); i++)  { printf ("------------------"); }  printf ("\n");
    printf ("%s\n", title);
    for (size_t i=0; i<functions.size(); i++)  { printf ("------------------"); }  printf ("\n");
    printf ("%3s\t", "# n");
    for (auto fct : functions)  {  printf ("%20s\t", fct.first);  }
    printf ("\n");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Check that alternative implementations provide the same result as the naive one
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void check (const FunctionsVector& functions, size_t nmin, size_t nmax)
{
    header ("CHECK (0 values means similar to naive approach)", functions);

    for (size_t n=nmin; n<=nmax; n++)
    {
        printf ("%3ld\t", n);

        CountVector reference = transfo_naive (getRandomVector(n));

        for (auto fct : functions)
        {
            // We call the (in place) transformation
            CountVector C = getRandomVector(n);
            (*fct.second) (C.data(), C.size());

            int nbDiffs= 0;
            for (size_t i=0; i<C.size(); i++)
            {
                if (reference[i]!=C[i]) { nbDiffs++; }
            }
            printf ("%20ld\t", nbDiffs);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Performance test
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void performance (const FunctionsVector& functions, size_t nmin, size_t nmax)
{
    header ("PERFORMANCE", functions);

    for (size_t n=nmin; n<=nmax; n++)
    {
        printf ("%3ld\t", n);
        for (auto fct : functions)
        {
            // We compute the average time for several executions
            // We use more executions for small n values in order
            // to have more accurate results
            size_t nbRuns = 1ULL<<(2+nmax-n);
            vector<double> timeValues;

            // We run the test several times
            for (size_t r=0; r<nbRuns; r++)
            {
                // We don't want to measure time for vector fill
                CountVector C = getRandomVector(n);

                double t0 = timestamp();
                (*fct.second) (C.data(), C.size());
                double t1 = timestamp();

                timeValues.push_back (t1-t0);
            }

            // We sort the vector of times in order to get the median value
            std::sort (timeValues.begin(), timeValues.end());

            double median = timeValues[timeValues.size()/2];
            printf ("%20lf\t", log(1000.0*1000.0*median)/log(2));
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t nmin = argc>=2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 14;
    size_t nmax = argc>=3 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 28;

    // We get a common random seed
    randomSeed = time(NULL);

    FunctionsVector functions = {
        make_pair ("transfo_recursive",        transfo_recursive),
        make_pair ("transfo_iterative",        transfo_iterative),
        make_pair ("transfo_avx2",             transfo_avx2),
        make_pair ("transfo_avx2_pcordes",     transfo_avx2_pcordes),
        make_pair ("transfo_recur_template",   transfo_recur_template),
        make_pair ("transfo_recur_thread",     transfo_recur_thread)
    };

    // We check for some n that alternative implementations
    // provide the same result as the naive approach
    check (functions, 5, 15);

    // We run the performance test
    performance (functions, nmin, nmax);
}
```

And here is the performance graph:
[image]

One can observe that the simple recursive implementation is pretty good, even compared to the AVX2 version. The iterative implementation is a little bit disappointing but I made no big effort to optimize it.

Finally, for my own use case with 32 bits counters and for n values up to 28, these implementations are obviously ok for me compared to the initial "naive" approach in O(4^n).

---

**Update**

Following some remarks from @PeterCordes and @chtz, I added the following implementations:

- `transfo-avx2-pcordes` : the same as `transfo-avx2` with some AVX2 optimizations
- `transfo-recur-template` : the same as `transfo-avx2-pcordes` but using C++ template specialization for implementing recursion
- `transfo-recur-thread` : usage of multithreading for the two initial recursive calls of `transfo-recur-template`

Here is the updated benchmark result:

[image]

A few remarks about this result:

1. the AVX2 implementations are logically the best options but maybe not with the maximum potential x8 speedup with counters of 32 bits
2. among the AVX2 implementations, the template specialization brings a little speedup but it almost fades for bigger values for n
3. the simple two-threads version has bad results for n<20; for n>=20, there is always a little speedup but far from a potential 2x.

Comment: Nice use of shuffling, somewhat similar to prefix sums, but the masking is different.  `ROTATE4` + AND with `k4`  could be just `vextracti128` (which leaves the upper bits of the ymm already zeroed), but I don't think there's an intrinsic that guarantees zero-extension.  (`_mm256_castsi128_si256` leaves the upper lane undefined.  Probably any sane compiler will end up with it zero-extended if you use it on the result of `_mm256_extracti128_si256`, but it's not technically safe.)  I guess you could use `vperm2i128` (`_mm256_permute2x128_si256`) with a zeroed vector.

Comment: `ROTATE2` AND `k2` can be done with one in-lane shuffle: `_mm256_bsrli_epi128(*source, 8);` which does separate byte-shifts in each lane, shifting in zeros.  Oh, so can the `ROTATE1` and `k1` shuffle.  You have `4,3,2,1` in the low lane, but you're actually masking off the `4`.  So yeah, you can save all those AND instructions, and use only in-lane shuffles for the first 2, making it significantly faster on Ryzen.  (Except that `vperm2i128` is really bad on Ryzen vs. `vextracti128` :/)  https://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: Oh, there's a `_mm256_zextsi128_si256` which we can use on the result of `_mm256_extracti128_si256` to hopefully compile to zero instructions.  So that's perfect.

Comment: You keep assigning to `*source` instead of a tmp var, and gcc can't prove that doesn't alias something else, I guess?  It actually stores after each step of those shuffles.  Oh, probably potential aliasing with those *non-const* `__m256i` variables you put a *global scope*!!!  Never do that; `_mm_set*` isn't constexpr, and stupid compilers actually copy at runtime to init a `static const __m256i k1 = _mm256_set_...`.  So don't do that either; put the shuffle constant inside the function that uses it and let the compiler merge duplicate constants like it does for string literals.

Comment: Oops, k1 isn't a byte-shift of the whole lane, you're grabbing the odd elements (high half of each 64 bit chunk).  Do that with a bit-shift.  Clang actually does that optimization for you, after you move the AND constants into the function where they become compile-time constants.  https://godbolt.org/z/N5xYiE  (clang's shuffle optimizer is pretty great.)  But we need to do it manually with intrinsics for gcc and other compilers.

Comment: Ok, https://godbolt.org/z/F4elYD is one instruction between each add, with no extra stores.  `_mm256_srli_epi64 ((s), 32)` then `_mm256_bsrli_epi128 ((s), 8)`, then `_mm256_zextsi128_si256(_mm256_extracti128_si256((s),1))` or `_mm256_permute2x128_si256((s),(s),0x81)`.  (`vperm2i128` can zero a lane if you set the high bit in that nibble of the imm8.)

Comment: Does the AVX2 version depend on N being a multiple of 8, or a power of 2 or something?  If called with `N<8`, it just returns without doing anything, and that could happen at the end of the recursion for starting values like N=28 -> 14 -> 7.  I guess for now it's a proof-of-concept without cleanup being implemented?  But you benchmarked it for many non-power-of-2 sizes.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: By construction, the test vectors have a size N=2^n (see function getRandomVector in the code). Actually, I'm interested in all possible n sets intersections, with 2^n possibilities. So yes, the AVX2 version (and the others) gets N being a power of 2, and since I care for "big" n values greater than 3, the recursion termination test for 2^n==8 is big enough (but I admit that a small check could not hurt)

Comment: ohhh, I missed that you had a log scale.  I was thinking `N` in the code was the same as `n` in the graph, and thinking those were pretty tiny problem sizes. :P  And BTW, re: a small check hurting: it already hurts the asm.  The compiler has to make code that returns without doing anything if neither condition is true, instead of just checking one cmp/jcc or fall through.  Suggestion: make a wrapper that checks `N & (N-1) == 0`, i.e. that N is a power of 2, before calling the real implementation.  Then omit checks in the implementation.  You might get a speedup, esp. with `gcc -fprofile-use`.

Comment: For the non-recursive version you should of course switch to a fully expanded SIMD version for sufficiently small sizes (e.g., what fits into your registers). There should be no conditional assignments (except for the loops).

Comment: I was also playing along with a fully-inlinable recursive variant: https://godbolt.org/z/FYcZHl (untested: maybe I mixed up left vs right shifts). Also I did not bother to write any non-recursive outer loop.

Comment: @chtz Nice, I will embed your function in my benchmark. And I like the template specialization ! I tried a template specialization version of my straightforward recursive version but there was not a big difference; maybe a decent modern compiler is more than able to make good usage of such a simple recursion.

Comment: According to different comments, I updated my answer.